# How I can send user-name & user-photo in whatsapp-web.js?

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

my code:

```
const art = require("ascii-art")
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const os = require("os")
const { Client, NoAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const { MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new NoAuth()
});

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('[+]Client is ready!');
    const number = "+79800409506, +79262261370";
    const text = "Hey douma!";
  // Getting chatId from the number.
  // we have to delete "+" from the beginning and add "@c.us" at the end of the number.
  const chatId = number.substring(1) + "@c.us";
 // Sending message.
 client.sendMessage(chatId, text);
});


client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.body === '!ping') {
        await message.reply('pong!');
    }
});
// client initialization...

client.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if (msg.body === '!everyone') {
        const chat = await msg.getChat();

        let text = 'ПРОСНИСЬ И ПОЙ!\n';
        let mentions = [];

        for (let participant of chat.participants) {
            mentions.push(`${participant.id.user}@c.us`);
            text += `@${participant.id.user} `;
        }

        await chat.sendMessage(text, { mentions });
    }
});

client.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if (msg.body === '!botAvatar') {
        const media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath('./favicon.ico');
        await client.sendMessage(msg.from, media);
    }
});
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if(msg.body === '!help') {
    const media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath('./douma-demon-slayer.gif')
    // your code here...
    await client.sendMessage(chatId, media, { caption: '[+]Это userbot oт zxck1llka/itzdouma!\n [++]*Команды:\n !botAvatar\n !everyone\n !ping\n [=]Разроботчик: сидит на аккe' });


  }
})
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.body ===)
})
client.initialize();
```

And I no idea how I can made this(

I don't have idea how I can made this(
666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666